# How do you add users multiple inputs to a list?

Tags: python, input

In terms of using this:

```
names = []  # Here we define an empty list.
while True:
    eingabe = input('Please enter a name: ')
    if not eingabe:
        break

    names.append(eingabe)
    print(eingabe)
```

How do you use it for multiple inputs?

Comment: What is you expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
names = []  # Here we define an empty list.
flag = True
while flag:
    eingabe = input('Please enter a name: ')
    if not eingabe:
        flag=False

    names.append(eingabe)
    print(eingabe)
```

So, until the flag not became False this while loop run continuously.
and if user does not entered any input value than it set the flag value False and loop will terminate.

Comment: What is the diff in `while True` and `while flag`?

Comment: This is the same code as what the OP posted (logically), and doesn't actually change / solve anything.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: actually the code in his answer seems to be clearly different from the OP's code...

Answer (score 1):

According to your question and given code above , it already takes multiple input from user but it seems that you are not printing them. If you want to get multiple input from user and add them to a empty list and print them out , then you've to change a bit more of your code.

```
names = []  
while True:
    eingabe = input('Please enter a name: ')
    if not eingabe:
        break

    names.append(eingabe)
print(names)
```

or you can do this simply just using `split()` method -

```
names = input('Enter name like : "apple microsoft facebook ...": ').split()
print(names)
```

Please let me know whether it is or not.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to convert multiple user inputs to a list, this will be the easiest way:

```
names = input('Please enter names (separated by space): ').split()
```